# how to increase GPS polling rate on Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, gps

Is there any way to increase the gps polling rate in my WP7 app?  Right now its updated roughly once a second.  I need at least three or four times as much resolution..

I was considering spawning multiple GeoCoordinateWatcher(s), each in their own thread, but that doesn't sound like it would work.

** a bit of background **
I'm trying to measure 0-60 with my application, but am quickly realizing when testing with cars that do sub 5 second 0-60 runs (GTR, ZR1, 911 turbo, etc), sampling once a second isn't going to give me an accurate result.

It sounds like I have to rely on the accelerometer to get this data and use the GPS data to correlate?

Comment: Just a side note:  some GPS chipsets only provide once/second updates.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can ask the GPS for its `Position` as often as you like... and this probably will result in serial calls to the "GPS chip" - so should get you more results back.

I definitely wouldn't spawn multiple Watchers - its just too hacky a solution - and could well go wrong (far too hard to get them to spread their results uniformly)

Also, more importantly in an A-GPS system on a typical phone, I doubt the GPS would be sufficiently accurate to really make it worthwhile calling more than once a second - even if you are in a car travelling at 120kmh I think that still only make 30 metres per second travel - and your phone will often be struggling to get the accuracy as close as 30 metres (from my observations so far on the RunSat results while cycling).

Comment: i agree.. a lot easier to deal with in a cycling application as speed does not change as quickly as, say, a car you're measuring 0-60 will.  I think the big question is "how" to ask for position as many times as I want.  by default, the GeoCoordinateWatcher will trigger the positionchanged event when it detects any motion (i have it set to 0) but even then it only fires about once a second.

Comment: From my observations on Garmin, WM6.5, iPhone, Bada and now WP7... speed isn't very accurate from small GPS units especially at low speed values - the GPS accuracy is at best just under 10m and this really impacts the speed accuracy. To be honest, if you were developing a 0->60 app, I don't think sampling rate would be your only challenge. If that is your target, it might be worth looking at using the accelerometer and some smoothing algorithm to assist your measurements. All GPS apps do smoothing - there's a lot of smoothing go on in the average sat nav.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Most GPS receivers installed in phones only calculate a solution @ 1 Hz.  Even if you manage to get the operating system to give you more frequent updates, the will only change value once per second.  The position calculation is done on an application specific IC, and it's programming cannot be altered.

GPS, in any case, is not a good solution for what you are trying.  Figure out how to use the accelerometers.  Integrate their values to get speed.